# I want to use the url I got as props from the styled component

Tags: styled-components

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const topCate = (props) => {
    return (
        <TopCateList imgObj>
            <p>{props.main_category_id}</p>
        </TopCateList>
    );
}

const TopCateList = styled.li`
    width: 130px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: .3em;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: .5em 0em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.975rem;
    background-image: url(${props => props.backImg});
    line-height: 3em;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-right: .5em;
`;



export default topCate;
```

I want to use the url I got as props from the styled component.
It is not displayed on the screen.
What should I do?

Comment: What is imgObj as shown in code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend a component in styled-components like in the code below :

Any props you pass in this component will be available to you as props like the `url`,`color` and `backImg`. Just make sure to pass the `className` to the `li` for it to apply the styles.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const List = (props) => {
    return (
        <li className={props.className}>
            <p>{props.url}</p>
        </li>
    );
}

const TopCateList = styled(List)`
    width: 130px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: .3em;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: .5em 0em;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.975rem;
    background-image: url(${props => props.backImg});
    line-height: 3em;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-right: .5em;
    color: ${props => props.color};
`;



export default TopCateList;
```

**Usage**

```
<TopCateList url="http://stackoverflow.com" color="red" backImg="./src/someimage.jpg">
```

Hope this helps !